# Haskell: Patterns matching error with my own type

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to take individual letter from user input string, follow a set of rule then give out encoded string. The parameters take a string, a cipher which is also a string and an integer. I've got some errors with  type matching. Here's my code

```
 encodeMessage :: [Char]->Cipher->Int -> [Char]
 encodeMessage (x:xs) [] _ = (x:xs)
 encodeMessage (x:xs) cp n
  | n>=0      = [(offsetRight (mod n 26) cp)!!((letterToNum x)-1)] ++ encodeMessage(xs cp n)
  | otherwise = [(offsetLeft (26-(mod n 26)) cp)!!((letterToNum x)-1)] ++ encodeMessage(xs cp n)
```

Here's the structure for Cipher `type Cipher = [Char]`.
Here's the error

```
SubstitutionCiphers.hs:95:71: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’
                  with actual type ‘Cipher -> Int -> [Char]’
    • Probable cause: ‘encodeMessage’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘encodeMessage (xs cp n)’
      In the expression:
        [(offsetRight (mod n 26) cp) !! ((letterToNum x) - 1)]
        ++ encodeMessage (xs cp n)
      In an equation for ‘encodeMessage’:
          encodeMessage (x : xs) cp n
            | n >= 0
            = [(offsetRight (mod n 26) cp) !! ((letterToNum x) - 1)]
              ++ encodeMessage (xs cp n)
            | otherwise
            = [(offsetLeft (26 - (mod n 26)) cp) !! ((letterToNum x) - 1)]
              ++ encodeMessage (xs cp n)

SubstitutionCiphers.hs:95:85: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Cipher -> Int -> [Char]’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • The function ‘xs’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘[Char]’ has none
      In the first argument of ‘encodeMessage’, namely ‘(xs cp n)’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘encodeMessage (xs cp n)’
```

Comment: `f(x y z)` is not the same as `f x y z` at all.

Comment: @amalloy that helps mate. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`encodeMessage(xs cp n)` means the function `xs` is applied to `cp` and `n`, and the result of that is then fed as a single argument to `encodeMessage`. Well, that's evidently rubbish, because `xs` is not a function at all! Also, `encodeMessage` has three arguments, not one, which is what GHC is quite clearly telling you there.

You evidently want `encodeMessage xs cp n`, which BTW is equivalent to all of the following:

```
((encodeMessage xs) cp) n
((encodeMessage xs) cp) (n)
((encodeMessage) xs) (cp) n
...
```

and also [semantically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to

```
encodeMessage (xs, cp, n)
```

...or, [more precisely](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v:uncurry),

```
uncurry (uncurry encodeMessage) ((xs, cp), n)
```

But it is not at all equivalent to `encodeMessage (xs cp n)`.

Comment: I think the semantic-equivalence point just confuses the issue.